# Print numbers every two blocks in a for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have the following loop:

```
for (let i=0; i<7; i+=2) {
  for (let j=i; j<i+2; j++) {
    console.log(j);
  }
  console.log('\n');
}
```

If I execute it I get:

```
0
1

2
3

4
5

6
7
```

But it only works on even conditions (0-7 = 8), if I instead put i<8, I get the same:

```
0
1

2
3

4
5

6
7
```

Which is bad, it must has returned 8 at the end, but instead doesn't print it. I expect my result when the condition is not even like this:

```
0
1

2
3

4
5

6
7

8
```

How can I achieve it? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although Nina's answer is better, for completeness, I post a corrected version of the code that you started with:

```js
let n = 8;
for (let i=0; i<=n; i+=2) {
  for (let j=i; j<i+2 && j <= n; j++) {
    console.log(j);
  }
  console.log('\n');
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use a single loop and add for each odd value a line feed after printing the value.

```js
for (let i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    if (i % 2) {
        console.log('\n');
    }
}
```